# Clojure, Leiningen, and CLASSPATH on Windows

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

What is the correct way to install Leiningen on Windows? I grabbed the script and did the self install. Tried to run *lein new tutorial* and got this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundExcep
tion: Could not locate leiningen/core__init.class or leiningen/core.clj on class
path:
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:417)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core_*init.
class or leiningen/core.clj on classpath:
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.core$load$fn*_4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
        at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
        ... 11 more

After getting this I added this to my class path:
C:\Users\Owner.lein\self-installs\leiningen-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Ran again and got same error. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
Went with 1.6.2 version based off suggestion from @mtyaka

Now I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodErr
or: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
        at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
        at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
        at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:417)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(IL
clojure/lang/Keyword;)V
        at leiningen.util.paths$native_arch_path.(paths.clj:32)
        at leiningen.util.paths_*init.load(Unknown Source)
        at leiningen.util.paths*_init.(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5352)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at leiningen.core$loading_*4414*_auto_*.invoke(core.clj:1)
        at leiningen.core*_init.load(Unknown Source)
        at leiningen.core_*init.(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
        at clojure.core$load$fn*_4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
        at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
        ... 11 more

Comment: Do you have a `CLASSPATH` variable set in your regular environment? Quicktime did that to me, and it broke leiningen.

Comment: this is my current CLASSPATH .;C:\jruby-1.5.0.RC3\lib\jruby.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\clojure-1.3.0\clojure-1.3.0.jar;C:\users\owner\.lein\self-installs\leiningen-1.6.2-standalone.jar

Comment: I get the same error without lein in the CLASSPATH

Comment: You might want to post on the leiningen google group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install leiningen 2 which is currently in the middle of development and is not really ready yet. I wouldn't be surprised if `self-install` doesn't work at the moment, especially on Windows.

Please try the [stable version of `lein.bat`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/raw/stable/bin/lein.bat) (currently 1.6.2).

Comment: So is lein.bat 1.6.2 compatible with Clojure 1.3.0?

Comment: Your leiningen projects are free to use any version of clojure, but having a specific version of clojure in your `CLASSPATH` could cause problems with leiningen 1.x... can you try removing Clojure 1.3 from the `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: Think I solved this one. Had the path to the Clojure jar file in CLASSPATH instead of just the path to the Clojure folder. Thanks.

Comment: @mtyaka Thanks!  You are the hero of the moment!  Once the path was set up right, the new lein.bat worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to draw attention to the solution, since right now it is found in the comments to the first answer.  If you are getting the xception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodErr... you need to delete the clojure jar file from your classpath.

I was using Leiningen 1.6.2 and clojure-1.3.0, as was brun, so can't say for sure if other versions have the same problem.